# Blogger Template Tag References

Tags: blogger

I am trying to find a comprehensive list of Blogger template tag references such as "post", "blog", and "top" attributes. There is many features on Blogger, but not documented very well. I found this: http://blogger2ools.mystady.com/, very large but not completed, and updated.

Is there any documentation like that for developing templates?

Answer (score 1):

I was/am looking for the same list. Until now, the only *"good"* stuff I found, was the standard Google Info that seems to be very thin, but here is the [List of Goolge](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=en) (date 15. Feb 2013)

For more information on how to development and so, there seems to be little information here is the link to the [*"Advanced-Section"*](https://support.google.com/blogger/topic/1711140?hl=en&ref_topic=1697868), but it has only some hints and pointers. Tutorials on the web don't seem to give much more information.

I hope this helps. If you found something else or better please share.

Comment: Blogger template tags have a horrible structure really, I was trying to build a local development tool, and it was almost finished, but finally I got really bored because of it, and gave up to develop it :)

Comment: I had the same problem, but i somehow always end up on my blogs, at least twice a year :) Than i update my template just a bit, and leave it for another 6 month, with the hope, the documentation improves until then. :)

Comment: Thats google behavior.. They bought sercives and do nothing then

Answer (score 1):

Try this link [GeekThis.com](http://geekthis.net/blog/132/blogger-theme-data-tags-for-widgets). At there you can find a lot of Blogger tags list.

And also you can test how thus tags behavior with download this link of xml template [DeveloperTheme-v0.0.1.zip](http://www.geekthis.net/uploads/projects/DeveloperTheme-v0.0.1.zip).

NOTE: Please backup your current page before you try this template provided by GeekThis.com! Or you can create another blog with some dummies post.

Regard.